# Dell PowerEdge 2900 rom Batt

Tags: dell-poweredge, controller, battery

I have a Dell PowerEdge 2900. I got the the Raid Controller battery warning that it had less than 24 hrs left on it. I replaced it with a new battery. However, after a week, the orange light at the back is still flashing and I still get the same message. During the boot-time, I get the message that the raid-controller battery is either, low, fully discharged, or not connected. I have checked the connection and rebooted the the sever several times without any results. I will appreciate your suggestions on this. Thank you.

Carl

Comment: Has the battery fully charged? Have you cleared the event from the hardware log? Is the BMC/ESM firmware up to date?

Comment: Disconnect all the power cables going to the server and hold then power button for 30-45 seconds then power back up.  This will clear the event logs and alarms on the server then see if it comes back.

Answer (score 1):

Update the controller firmware, clear the archived message in your BIOS, else it's a DOA battery.

Answer (score 0):

I expirienced such issue with one of company Dell PE servers  ("false-positive" low battery warning -  I've replaced failed battery not only with new battery but with battery from other server, so I'm sure it was Ok) and it's gone only after flashing new PERC controller firmware.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If the battery is 4+ years old, replace it, whatever your other concerns....